# Interpreting command substitution from a variable in bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, command-substitution

For the following value of FOO:

```
$ FOO='echo `echo hello`'
$ $FOO
`echo hello`
```

how can I get the expected output:

```
hello
```

Basically, how can I interpret a command substitution in the contents of a variable?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: This is not a XY problem. This is a legitimate question for a legitimate problem, and in my particular case, this is the only way to accomplish what I need to do (see my comment in the answer). I could include details about my setup and why I'm using command substitution in an environment variable, but that is outside the scope of providing an answer (along with any precautionary warnings) to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering the question as given,

```
eval $FOO
```

but you're probably going about your real problem the wrong way.

Comment: This is correct, but I can't bring myself to upvote it because it contains the word `eval`.

Comment: @suvayu It's a security risk, since you may not be able to completely control the value of the string that it gets as an argument. It's similar to an SQL injection attack. In this example, an attacker may be able to sneak `FOO="rm -rf /" into the code. It's safer to avoid `eval` if possible (and it usually is).

Comment: This is for a (not so) simple macro which executes a shell script which has command substitutions in it.  I need to pass the script via environment variable and then execute it atomically.  As such, security is not a concern in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$ FOO="echo `echo hello`"
$ $FOO
```

Just replace **single quotes** with **double quotes**.

Comment: From the wording of the question, I think the single quotes are intentional. The OP wants the command substitution deferred until the variable is expanded.

Comment: see i thought he is using the command and is not getting proper output....dats why i answered saying "Just replace single quotes with double quotes"...