# Backticks can't handle pipes in variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem with one script in bash with CAT command.

This works:

```
 #!/bin/bash
fil="| grep LSmonitor";
log="/var/log/sys.log ";
lines=`cat $log | grep LSmonitor | wc -l`;
echo $lines;
```

Output: 139

This does not:

```
#!/bin/bash
fil="| grep LSmonitor";
log="/var/log/sys.log ";

string="cat $log $fil | wc -l";
echo $string;
`$string`;
```

Output:

```
cat /var/log/sys.log | grep LSmonitor | wc -l
cat: opcion invalida -- 'l'
Pruebe 'cat --help' para mas informacion.
```

$fil is a parameter in this example static, but in real script, parameter is get from html form POST, and if I print I can see that the content of $fil is correct.

Comment: what do you expect count to be sum of two files?

Comment: A filter, I have an HTML that has 2 inputs.

select -> List of all logs
filter -> The filter that the sysadmin can write

Image: http://i.imgur.com/j1WLkDu.png

So i get the filter imput from "read" , but when I want use cat $log $fil I get an error. So I need to know the lines for do a while with head and tail pipes for show only the info filtered.

Comment: You're using the `cat ... | grep` antipattern. Just `grep` the file, don't `cat` it through to `grep`. Also, you should use quotes (`""`) here. So try `\`"$string"\``. This is almost certainly the wrong way to solve your problem though, but you've given too little information for me to suggest a better way.

Comment: I just want, do this

cat /var/log/syslog | grep LSmonitor | wc -l

using variables

cat $logfile $filter | wc -l

If I copy 'cat /var/log/syslog | grep LSmonitor | wc -l' in console, console returns 139.. so I think is not a problem with cat & grep.

http://i.imgur.com/T0X5p4S.png

Comment: [Storing commands in strings isn't a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I think what you really want is `grep LSmonitor /var/log/syslog | wc -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, allow me to say that this sounds like a really bad idea:

> […] in real script, parameter is get from html form POST, […]

You should not be allowing the content of POST requests to be run by your shell. This is a massive attack vector, and whatever mechanisms you have in place to try to protect it are probably not as effective as you think.

Secondly, `|` inside variables are not treated as special. This isn't specific to backticks. Parameter expansion (e.g., replacing `$fil` with `| grep LSmonitor`) happens *after* the command is parsed and mostly processed. There's a little bit of post-processing that's done on the results of parameter expansion (including "word splitting", which is why `$fil` is equivalent to the three arguments `'|' grep LSmonitor` rather than to the single argument `'| grep LSmonitor'`), but nothing as dramatic as you describe. So, for example, this:

```
pipe='|'
echo $pipe cat
```

prints this:

```
| cat
```

Since your use-case is so frightening, I'm half-tempted to *not* explain how you can do what you want — I think you'll be better off *not* doing this — but since Stack Overflow answers are intended to be useful for more people than just the original poster, an example of how you can do this is below. I encourage the OP not to read on.

---

```
fil='| grep LSmonitor'
log=/var/log/sys.log

string="cat $log $fil | wc -l"
lines="$(eval "$string")"
echo "$lines"
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, since you're building a pipeline as a string, you would need:

```
eval "$string"
```

But **DON'T DO THIS!!!!** -- someone can easily enter the filter

```
; rm -rf *
```

and then you're hosed.

If you want a regex-based filter, get the user to just enter the regex, and then you'll do:

```
grep "$fil" "$log" | wc -l
```

Comment: Even worse is `; rm -rf /*`, especially with elevated privileges.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `eval` (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531431/2687324).

It looks like it's interpreting `|` as a string, not a pipe, so when it reaches `-l`, it treats it as if you're trying to pass in `-l` to `cat` instead of `wc`.

The other answers outline why you shouldn't do it this way.

`grep LSmonitor /var/log/syslog | wc -l` will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Is the downvote(s) for "this is a really bad idea in the first place and don't do it?" An explanation will be helpful. (I agree you should never do this).